# How can i change the wso2 main template

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

How can i change the wso2 main template (Management console) of the base link 'https://localhost:9443/carbon/'. I would like to change the layout and maybe logo's or something like that.

If anyone could help me i would be quite grateful.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following doc is from Identity Server. But it should work for all carbon products.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Customizing+the+Management+Console

Comment: Thank you Bhathiya. I was not finding. I will test here the tutorial, and as soon as it worked i end up the question.

Comment: Thank you very much Bhathiya. I was able to solve my problem. I will end the question.